# Motion layout with individual moveWhenScrollAtTop flag for views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-motionlayout

I want to create a screen with a motion layout, here is the layout scheme:[image: layout scheme]

1. Header visible if a user is on top of the RecyclerView, otherwise it's gone;
2. Filters visible if the user swipes up, gone if swipes down.

There are problems, that I don't know, how I can use simultaneously `moveWhenScrollAtTop=true` for header content view and `moveWhenScrollAtTop=false` for filters. I tried making it with the transition chain, but it doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/start"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/state_header_hidden"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/state_idle">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:moveWhenScrollAtTop="true"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/mainRv" />
    </Transition>

    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/end"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/state_filters_hidden"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/state_header_hidden">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:moveWhenScrollAtTop="false"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/mainRv" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/state_idle">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/headerRv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/filtersRv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingHorizontal="12dp"
            android:paddingVertical="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headerRv" />

        <ConstraintOverride
            android:id="@id/mainRv"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/state_header_hidden">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/headerRv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/filtersRv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingHorizontal="12dp"
            android:paddingVertical="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headerRv" />

        <ConstraintOverride
            android:id="@id/mainRv"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/state_filters_hidden">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/headerRv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/filtersRv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingHorizontal="12dp"
            android:paddingVertical="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ConstraintOverride
            android:id="@id/mainRv"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore" />

    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `app:onTouchUp="decelerateAndComplete"` as
https://mikescamell.com/motionlayoutquickie-ontouchup/